# Dynamically adding onmouseover attributes to anchor tags

Tags: javascript, dom, addition, onmouseover

I generate all the pages on my web site (www.ibiblio.org/britishraj) from MS word documents, with a Java app I created from scratch.  I need to do this in an automated fashion as there are 35 large books of up to 500 pages each, totalling over 4 million words, several thousand footnotes, and over a thousand images.

I'd like to add popup footnotes and popup images, while keeping my html as much free of javascript as possible. I can do it if I add an onmouseover= to every footnote tag and every image tag.  I have that working in a test file.

<a class="fnr" href="#" onmouseover="showfootnote(456, this);">456</a>>

The rerence to 'this' is needed to decide where to show the popup.  There may be as many as one hundred of these in any one chapter, twenty chapters per book, 35 books...

So ... how can I add the onmouseover attribute dynamically?  I have heard there is some way of iterating the DOM after loading the page, and adding the extra attribute based on the class of the tag, in ths case clss="fnr".  I would also need to pass in the number as a parameter, in this case 456, which is the innerhtml of the anchor tag.

I have seen some examples of things slightly similar but not exactly what I need.  I've been struggling with it for a few days and not been successful.  My javascript skills are lacking here.

Help/advice would be welcome.

.... Now I am a little wiser I know that JQuery can do this with ease. ....

Answer (score 2):

Put an id to the tag(for easy access), for ex, id="myID". Where you want to add the onmouseover attribute, use:

```
document.getElementById("myID").onmouseover=/*your function name*/;
```

The above is DOM1 compatibe. 
For DOM2, you can use addEventListener methods. Google it -_-.

As far as your code goes specifically, you can iterate over all your IDs and use

```
document.getElementById("myID").onmouseover=function(){showfootnote(456, document.getElementById("myID"));};
```

Functionality wont change if you use the above code. :) Hope this helps.